# Does the amount of creatures I have affect the birth rate?

Tags: incremental-zoo

Does the amount of creatures in an enclosure affect how quickly you get more creatures? In other words, is it more efficient to sell creatures in smaller increments so that they multiply faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just attempted selling several Meerkats and noticed the Birth Rate value started to decrease for every 1,000 that I sold. So the answer appears to be yes, more creatures means you have a higher birth rate (and death rate).